# struts2 - is it possible to accept request parameters in the form of a map in the action class?

Tags: struts2, struts

I have a class like :

```
class FileAction{
   Map<FilterType, String> grades;
 ....
}
```

`FilterType` is an `enum` with values : `GroupFilter`, `TimeFilter`, etc. Now, every filter should have a corresponding value (like `GroupFilter` would have a corresponding `groupId`).

I wish to pass the filter type with the filter value from the UI, and receive it in the action class. Is there any way to pass data from UI that can be automatically translated to a map present in the action class ?

Answer (score 2):

yeah, struts2 has type conversion, you should take a look at the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-AnadvancedexampleforindexedListsandMaps) and this example on [Vita Rara](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/updating_a_list_of_domain_entities).

Answer (score 1):

Well Struts2 is capable enough to convert data send from UI to `Map` provided it should know to the `Struts2` type convertors, unfortunately no one system is intelligent enough to know all available data types so we need to tell the system about our custom types as well way to convert them

You need to create your own custom type convertor for this.Have a look at official doc about creating custom [type convertors](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/type-conversion.html)

Comment: If I send url?grades['GroupFilter']=3&grades['TimeFilter']=4, won't it look for the 'grade' param, and assign GroupFilter as a key, and 3 as value for the map ?

Comment: yes it will until unless they are known type, in you case if you put type as String and say Integer it will work perfectly, but if you want them to be treated something else as per your data type tell it to S2 and S2 will convert and populate them for you.

Comment: actually, it works if you pass the parameters like url?filters['GroupFilter']=3&filters['TimeFilter']=2;
without any type converters